Craft update fails (Craft 5.2.8 > latest)
From the command line, craft update fails. Ideas?
[versastudio@www craft]$ php craft update/craft
Unknown command: update/craft
Caused by: Exception 'yii\base\InvalidRouteException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request: update/craft'

in /home/domains/versa/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php:149

Stack trace:
#0 /home/domains/versa/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Controller.php(180): yii\base\Controller->runAction()
#1 /home/domains/versa/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/console/ControllerTrait.php(89): yii\console\Controller->runAction()
#2 /home/domains/versa/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/console/Controller.php(216): craft\console\Controller->traitRunAction()
#3 /home/domains/versa/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(552): craft\console\Controller->runAction()
#4 /home/domains/versa/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(180): yii\base\Module->runAction()
#5 /home/domains/versa/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/console/Application.php(91): yii\console\Application->runAction()
#6 /home/domains/versa/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(147): craft\console\Application->runAction()
#7 /home/domains/versa/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/console/Application.php(122): yii\console\Application->handleRequest()
#8 /home/domains/versa/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(384): craft\console\Application->handleRequest()
#9 /home/domains/versa/craft/craft(13): yii\base\Application->run()
#10 {main}


It's because update/craft isn't a valid command. Valid commands are:

update/info to list available updates
update/update to install them.
update can be used as a shortcut for both commands. Without any parameters, it's a shortcut for update/info. With parameters, it's a shortcut for update/update.

Run php craft update craft to update only Craft itself, and php craft update all to update Craft and all installed plugins.
